# Saving Date & Time to mysql on click

Tags: php, mysql

I have a login page when the user enters their username and password and click login I automatically want it to log the date and time in the database. How can I do this?

Comment: mysql has this handy function called `NOW()`, which returns the current date/time.  Just run an update query on their record, or an insert to a log table, and set the login date to `NOW()`

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it manually, like:

```
UPDATE USERS SET LAST_LOGIN = NOW() WHERE USER_ID = ?
```

Comment: can you confirm:  $sql = "UPDATE users SET logindate = NOW() WHERE username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']) . "'";

Comment: @Jacob, I don't know how your code is organized, so that means little to me. You should update the `users` table in the same file as you check the username and password. Post your code if you need us to take a closer look.

Comment: Its very tempramental sometimes works sometimes does not. http://pastebin.com/XmTjWnvW

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a table "log" with two columns: username and datetime.

Then, whenever the user clicks login, post a command to a php script that executes the following sql statement:

```
insert into database.log values (username, CURDATE());
```

?

Hope it helps.
Let me know if you need more spceific guidance :)

Comment: `CURDATE` only returns the date. `NOW` would be more appropriate, but a good suggestion anyway, +1.